# python subprocess and catching stdout of bash's `history` command

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am just trying to catch the output of the `history` command from python via subprocess... and it doesn't work:

```
import shlex, subprocess, time, os, sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

command_line = "history"
args = shlex.split(command_line)
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what doesn't work?

Comment: I *think* I've edited the question to mean what you meant (in which case, it is a duplicate). If not, edit it yourself to make it more clear.